# Sequelize 5 findOrCreate with undelete inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a simple table of users in Postgres that looks like this:

```
Column     |            Type             |
-----------+-----------------------------+
 id        | integer                     |
 name      | text                        |
 email     | text                        |
 nickname  | text                        |
 deletedAt | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "unique_user" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name, email)
```

When I get a request on my API with users data, I want to create new users. If the user is soft-deleted, then I'd like to undelete them and if the user exists already, then do nothing.

```js
const users = [];
_.each(req.body.users, (user) => {
  const u = Users.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email
    },
    defaults: {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      nickname: user.nickname
    },
    paranoid: false,
    transaction
  }).spread(async (returnedUser, created) => {
    if (!created) {
      if (returnedUser.deletedAt) {
        await returnedUser.update({ deletedAt: null, transaction });
        await returnedUser.save({ transaction });
      }
    }
  })
  users.push(u);
});
```

It all seems to work except for the undeleting portion. It does not seem like an error is thrown, but the matching soft-deleted user remains deleted. I am using sequelize 5.

Comment: Since sequelize.js function/methods might varies a lot from version to version, please incldue which version of sequelize.js you are using

Comment: There is a problem in the updation part. First off, the `transaction` must be a part of the options and not the values for `returnedUser.update`. The correct syntax would be `await returnedUser.update({ deletedAt: null}, {transaction});`. Secondly, calling the save is redundant if you update the instance calling the `update` method.

Comment: @GhassanMaslamani updated to state it's sequelize 5.